# How to post data dynamically added by user in asp.net mvc 4 model dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to implement Create/Edit functionality using model dialog in ASP.NET MVC 4 with Entity Framework database first approach as per given below image:

[image]

I have gone through the following article on net while searching solution for this.

[**CLICK HERE TO BROWSE**](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/279bc324-5be3-4156-a9e9-dd91c971d462/?CRUD%20operation%20using%20Modal%20dialog%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC)

It's very much similar what i want but the only difference is that in my case Emp name and Emp code is static but a user can add rows dynamically at client side in **Field 1** , **Field 2** , and **Comments** section so in this case how to save(create/Edit) data( dynamically added by user ) into database.

**tblEmployee** --> this table has EmpID, Emp name and Emp code column

**tblTable1** --> this table has ID(primary key),EmpID(foreign key),Detail1

**tblTable2** --> this table has ID(primary key),EmpID(foreign key),Detail2

Do I have to do use json/ajax approach or something else you suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In you controller's parameters set your dynamic properties as arrays.

When you add a new row on the client side, name your control the same as what the parameter name would be. ie:

```
<input type="text" name="Detail1[0]" />
<input type="text" name="Detail1[1]" />
<input type="text" name="Detail1[2]" />
```

When you post to this controller, you should see all of the dynamic data has filled your arrays.  You can handle the keys when it gets there.

Comment: Can we do it using JSON data post approach?

Comment: I can send list of values added dynamically but how to map that values with their id in database table because I'm only sending values not id of each values.

i.e. how can I sure that i'm going to update correct row in database table?

Comment: I tried this but when I add texbox dynamically and post to controller action I get only one value not other which I added dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If user can add `Detail1`, `Detail2` and `Comment` by dynamically, define them as model, then add  to action like following:

```
public class Detail1 {
   public string Content {get; set;}
}

public class Detail2 {
   public string Content {get; set;}
}

public class Comment {
   public string Content {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string EmpName, string EmpCode, List<Detail1> detail1s, List<Detail2> detail2s, List<Comment> comments)
{
    //save operations...
}
```

And view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
// other static fields..

<input type="button" value="Add Detail1" onclick="AddDetail1();" />
<input type="button" value="Add Detail2" onclick="AddDetail2();" />
<input type="button" value="Add Comment" onclick="AddComment();" />

<table id="LeftDetails1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Detail 1
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<table id="RightDetails2">
        <tr>
            <td>
               Detail 2
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<table id="BottomComments">
        <tr>
            <td>
               Comments
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddDetail1() {
        var rowDetail1 = $('#LeftDetails1 tr').length;
        var index = rowDetail1 + 1;
        $('#LeftDetails1').append("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='detail1s.Index' value='" + index + "' /><input type='text' name='detail1s[" + index + "].Content' /></td></tr>");
    }

    function AddDetail2() {
        var rowDetail2 = $('#RightDetails2 tr').length;
        var index = rowDetail2 + 1;
        $('#RightDetails2').append("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='detail2s.Index' value='" + index + "' /><input type='text' name='detail2s[" + index + "].Content' /></td></tr>");
    }

    function AddComment() {
        var rowComment = $('#BottomComments tr').length;
        var index = rowComment + 1;
        $('#BottomComments').append("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='comments.Index' value='" + index + "' /><input type='text' name='comments[" + index + "].Content' /></td></tr>");
    }
</script>
```

And you can give value of `EmpId` to 3 models after employee save. Firstly save employee, then you will get it's `Id`, then give taht value to `Detail1`, `Detail2` and `Comment` models and save again.

Hope, this will work.