# kotlin recyclerview display sqlite parent and child table data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Our question is about database design or how to view a parent table and child table in a recyclerview widget?

This is the view we want

PRODUCE
tomatoes
avocados

LIQUOR
beer

The Department table model looks like this IT IS THE PARENT

```
class ViewDeptModel(
    var idD:Int = 0
    var dept:String = ""
)
```

The Item table model is the same IT IS THE CHILD

```
class ViewItemModel(
    var idI:Int = 0
    var item:String = ""
)
```

So to view the data in the recyclerview we thought about using this model

```
data class ParentModel(
    val title : String = "",
    val children : List<ViewItemModel>
)
```

So first Dept is displayed then the corresponding children are displayed
**How do we know when the children associated with Parent(dept) are finished?**
So the next Parent will be displayed with its children

If we give the Child table a Foreign Key that refers to the Parent id this prevents the use of JOINS and UNIONS

So looking at For Next Loop like the 4 year old Java code at this link below
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808297/how-to-get-parent-and-child-table-title-using-nested-foreach-loop-in-entity-fram)

We are a bit lost where to put some of this code. In the ViewActivity that displays the data. Do we add the In action collect data code to the ViewActivity?
It would appear it is its own Class
We are assuming the For Next loop goes in the ViewActivity. 
How this code works is where we are really lost!

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductUserViewModel>

foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <li>@item.User.Name</li>
   foreach(var product in item.Products)
   {
     <li>@product.Name</li>
   }
}
```

If we need to loose the idea of a third Model and For Next Loops we are happy to listen

Comment: @MikeT We could use your expertise When Ever you have time PLEASE

Comment: Why does a FK prevent JOINS and UNIONs? I think your question needs more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all data can be loaded from the database in the following form:

Department:

```
data class Department(val id: Int, val title: String, val children: ArrayList<Item>)
```

Item:

```
data class Item(val id: Int, val title: String)
```

it is possible to calculate the positions of the departments in the list. For example, the first department is at index 0, the second one is located at `departments.get(0).children.size + 1`, and so on.

The full code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val data = arrayListOf<Department>(
            Department(0, "Department1",
                    arrayListOf(
                            Item(0, "Item1.1"),
                            Item(1, "Item1.2"),
                            Item(3, "Item1.3")
                    )),
            Department(0, "Department2",
                    arrayListOf(
                            Item(0, "Item2.1")
                    )),
            Department(0, "Department3",
                    arrayListOf(
                            Item(0, "Item3.1"),
                            Item(1, "Item3.2")
                    )),
            Department(0, "Department4",
                    arrayListOf(
                            Item(0, "Item4.1"),
                            Item(1, "Item4.2"),
                            Item(1, "Item4.3")
                    ))
    )

    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler_view.adapter = Adapter(this, data)

}
}

class Adapter(val context: Context, val list: ArrayList<Department>): RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {

var total: Int = 0
var sectionIndices: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()
var sectionSizes: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf()

init{
    var index = 0
    var pos = 0
    for (d in list){
        sectionIndices.add(pos)
        sectionSizes.add(d.children.size)
        pos += (1 + d.children.size)
        index += 1
    }
    total = pos
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false)
    return VH(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return total
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
    for (section in 0 .. sectionIndices.size - 1){
        if (position >= sectionIndices.get(section)
                && position <= sectionIndices.get(section) + sectionSizes.get(section)){
            val i = position - sectionIndices.get(section)
            when (i){
                0 -> {
                    // department
                    val department = list.get(section)
                    holder.textView.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
                    holder.textView.text = department.title
                }
                else -> {
                    // item
                    val item = list.get(section).children.get(i - 1)
                    holder.textView.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT
                    holder.textView.text = item.title
                }
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
}

class VH(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

val textView: TextView
init {
    textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)
}

}

data class Department(val id: Int, val title: String, val children: ArrayList<Item>)

data class Item(val id: Int, val title: String)
```

Comment: I understand the increment the Department based on size I think what I may not have explained is we have no idea how many Items are in the Items table So with your code if Dept 0 have 3 children and Dept 1 has 5 children how will your code know to place child 3 in Dept 1 by the by here is link to code https://medium.com/@navendra/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047 will try to test your code

Comment: Then please clarify your problem: do you have a plain RecyclerView or a nested RecyclerView from https://medium.com/@navendra/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047? Do you have already the code for loading Departments/Items from the database, or the goal is to write it?

Comment: We can create the two tables with data this is done The nested recyclerview is not written yet but we plan to follow the medium.com code JUST replace the data supply with the SQLite data We can view the two tables We are calling this the BackEnd or just a way to create the tables issue is LINKING the tables for the nested recyclerview OR displaying the data SORRY for the late reply

Comment: If loading data from database is the main goal then it can be done using SQLiteDatabase.query() (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). I created a sample https://github.com/atarasenko/nestedRecycler

Comment: The GitHub code for the DB and Application too many errors when I try to use it Will see if I can FIX errors on my end may be running on your side Thanks for being persistent

Comment: We solved this question the answer is at this Stackoverflow question enjoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747527/kotlin-recyclerview-data-not-showing-solved